# Extract to rows in python/pandas

Tags: dataframe, extract, reshape

i have data merged into 1 cell in a .csv separated by semicolons, trying to get them into their own cells inserted below each other.  Very similar to excel "split text to columns' but need them to go into rows and align underneath each other.

current datafame:[image]

Final Goal:[image]

Data Being Used:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxJC9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  .str.split(';') to expand the columns. The tricky think is to deal with columns which do not need to be splitted. In my mind is simpler to actually convert them into the same 'string with comma' style of the other columns and then just iterate over all columns and expand everything. Here a piace of code with a reduce version of the dataset. Hope it will help you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'User ID':[1,2],'salary':['65000;120000;70000','65000;120000;70000'],'gender':['male;male;female', 'male;male;female']})

print(df)
```

Out:

```
   User ID              salary            gender
0        1  65000;120000;70000  male;male;female
1        2  65000;120000;70000  male;male;female
```

asd

```
cols_to_split = ['salary', 'gender']
cols_no_split = ['User ID']
expanded_rows = {}

# need the number of splits to fill 
n_splits = len(df[cols_to_split[0]].loc[0].split(";"))

# expand elements of columns with single values to fit the same format of the others 
for col in cols_no_split:
  df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: ''.join([str(x)+';' for i in range(n_splits)]))
  df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x[:-1])

# iterate through every column to expand them 
for col in (cols_no_split + cols_to_split):

  expanded_rows[col] = df[col].str.split(';').apply(pd.Series,1).stack().values


df_final = pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows)

print(df_final)
```

Out:

```
  User ID  salary  gender
0       1   65000    male
1       1  120000    male
2       1   70000  female
3       2   65000    male
4       2  120000    male
5       2   70000  female
```

Comment: Hi thanks for this, curious why I'd be getting "arrays must all be same length" error.  It's calling from a 'pd.read_csv(.csv) ' . Seems like I'm having an issue with pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows) line of code possible.  thanks again. I've been working on this issue for a month now : (

Comment: I put a screenshot titled 'Data Being Used' above in the question.

Comment: The error tells you that you have some lines with more columns than the number of headers (i.e. the columns names). To avoid this error you can: -check which line have more columns and delete the extra cells -import only the relevant column using pd.read_csv('filename.csv', columns=['User ID', 'salary', 'gender']) (I wrote three columns but you can add more names) -try to open the file line by line but I would suggest to keep trying with pandas first.

Comment: ok, sorry I'm having trouble following regarding understanding your first sentence,  but i should start with only 3 columns as opposed to all 9 or 10 and see how that goes?

Comment: You can also keep all columns, the point is that you have to tell pandas to ignore extra cells which appear in columns without name. To do so, either you delete those cell in the original csv file, or you specify with the 'names' argument (not columns, sorry, I recall the wrong word) the columns  that you want to read, and pandas will ignore the extra cells automatically. So the line would be df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', names=['Response ID', 'employees_in_position', 'full_time_only_salary', 'gender', 'hourly_wage', 'job_title', 'minimum_education', 'minimum_years_experience', 'race'])